# Firebase for Java

Tags: java, firebase, sdk

I don't know if i'm asking a stupid question or what but since Google Analytics will be replaced with Firebase SDK, I'm gonna ask if there's an implementation to a Java application (Eclipse Plugin)?

I still want to retain the current implementation that it will get the country, city, language, PC hostname of the user.

Is the Admin SDK for Java for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Admin SDK for that.
[Firebase Admin SDK](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjUp5OIyJfgAhWBZVAKHXhHD20QFjAAegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fadmin%2Fsetup&usg=AOvVaw2uwwBdur_zSHKNn6XAjN56)